# What's the difference between document.property and document.get('property')?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoose document that has timestamps option enabled. I want to make decisions based on this timestamps but I noticed something weird according to my understanding.

I tried to get those values the traditional way (`document.createdAt`) but that returns `undefined`. But if I use `document.get('createdAt')` the value comes as in the database. The docs don't say anything about this. My question is: ¿Why timestamps behave this way?

### Edit

The schema I'm using has an array of embedded schemas:

```
const Customer = new mongoose.Schema({
    roles: {
      type: [{
        type: String,
        enum: 'app b2b iot'.split(' '),
      }],
      default: 'app',
      set: (value = []) => (value.includes('app')
        ? value
        : value.concat('app')),
    },
    email: {
      address: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        set(email) {
          this._previousEmail = this.email.address
          return email
        },
      },
      verified: {
        type: Boolean,
      },
      token: String,
    },
    nickname: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
    },
    recoveryToken: String,

    gender: String,
    birthday: String,
    lastLogin: Date,
    isAnonymous: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    devices: [Device],
});
```

Device schema:

```
const Device = new mongoose.Schema({
    customer: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Customer',
      required: true,
    },
    handle: {
      type: String,
    },
    platform: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      set: toLowerCase,
    },
    info: Mixed,
    smartFilterTags: [{
      type: String,
    }],
    paidUntil: Date,
    nh: {
      tier: String,
      _id: {
        type: ObjectId,
      },
    location: {
      type: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Point'],
        default: 'Point',
      },
      coordinates: [{
        type: Number,
      }],
    },
  })
```

I have a base plugin that apply when I compile models:

```
function basePlugin(schema) {
    schema.add({
      archivedAt: Date,
    })

    schema.set('timestamps', true)

    schema.set('toJSON', {
      virtuals: true,
    })

    schema.set('toObject', {
      virtuals: true,
    })
}
```

Comment: can you show me your schema?

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I edited the post to show my schema composition